# Issue with Routing logic and React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Im building a small application where i have used ReactJs for the front end and node express with jwt and passport in back end. Im using react router v4 and i have configured the applications routes like this.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Login from './login/login';
import Signup from './signup/signup';
import Account from './account/account';
import Navigation from './navigation/navigation';
import Newsfeeds from './newsfeed/feedcontainer';
import Test from './test';
import NotMatch from './nomatch/Notmatch';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const history = createBrowserHistory({});
injectTapEventPlugin();

let hasToken = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');
  return (token == undefined);
}

class App extends Component{

  render(){
    return(
      <MuiThemeProvider>
       <Router history={history}>
         <Switch>
           <Route path="/login" exact component={Login}/>
           <Route path="/signup" exact component={Signup}/>
           <Route path="/test" exact component={Test}/>
            <Navigation>
             <Route path="/account" exact render={() => (hasToken() ? (<Account />) : (<Redirect to="/login"/>))}/>
             <Route path="/home"  exact render={() => (hasToken() ? (<Newsfeeds />) : (<Redirect to="/login"/>))}/>
           </Navigation>
           <Route component={NotMatch}/>
         </Switch>
       </Router>
     </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

The code for logout

```
<Link to="/login"><MenuItem primaryText="Logout" onTouchTap={e=>{localStorage.clear();}}></MenuItem></Link>
```

When ever i try to logout(clear my localstorage and redirect to login route) it gets stuck in loop and the app breaks. How to avoid this?
How to restrict/authenticate routes. When already logged switch to home page when user tries to move to `/login` or `/signup` routes.

Comment: Did you use the ternary correctly? `hasToken()` returns true if the user is login right? If so, you have the Redirects mixed up.

Comment: @Hoyen yes the ternary is correct i will update the question with hasToken()

Comment: Can you add the part where you are trying to logOut

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I've Updated the code